# After Trigger for Update and Insert failing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a trigger for keeping audit record for one table for Insert and Update records.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppLog](
[TableName] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
[ColumnName] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
[RecordId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[OldValue] [varchar](2000) NULL,
[NewValue] [varchar](2000) NULL,
[UpdatedBy] [varchar](200) NULL,
[UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons](
[Personid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Age] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER AuditRecord ON dbo.Persons
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO AppLog
    (TableName ,ColumnName ,RecordId ,OldValue ,NewValue ,UpdatedBy ,UpdatedOn )
        SELECT 'Persons', 'LastName', COALESCE(i.Personid,NULL), 
                                    d.LastName, i.LastName, CURRENT_USER, GETDATE()
            FROM Persons pv
            LEFT JOIN INSERTED i ON pv.Personid = i.Personid
            LEFT JOIN DELETED d ON pv.Personid = d.Personid;
GO

INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,age)
VALUES ('Satish','Parida',40);

INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,age)
VALUES ('SKP','Tada',90);
```

The last insert is failing as it is trying to insert null to recordid column in applog table, could someone explain or fix the issue.

Comment: Looking at your `INSERT`, you have the value `COALESCE(i.Personid,NULL)` for `RecordId`. There's your problem. That statement might as well be `i.Personid` (`NULL` will be returned if the value of `i.Personid` is `NULL`), and as you're performing a `LEFT JOIN` to `inserted`, it could easily have the value `NULL`. I *suspect* you don't even need to rerference `Persons ` in your `FROM` in the trigger.

Comment: You suffer from "one table to rule them all". While this might seem like an effective way to log or audit changes, anyone will struggle to get useful information from it. You should think long and hard about this design and how you (others - really) intend to use this. I also see an assumption - that every table has a single column primary key which can be implicitly convert to varchar(20). Yes - many struggles are likely ahead of someone.

Comment: @SMor I am looking forward to make the common part of the code to be a Stored Procedure, where I can use the table name,  Audit column and the primary key as input to the SP. I am hitting a wall hear as I have to use dynamic SQL if I try doing that, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that is failing is the one below:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,age)
VALUES ('SKP','Tada',90);
```

This is because in your Trigger you are using `Persons` are your "base" table and the performing a `LEFT JOIN` to both `inserted` and `deleted`. As result when you try to perform the above `INSERT`, values from the previous `INSERT` are used as well in the trigger's dataset. The person `'Parida'` doesn't appear in the table `inserted` for your second `INSERT`, and so `COALESCE(i.Personid,NULL)` returns `NULL`; as I mentioned in my comment, there' no point using `COALESCE` to return `NULL`, as if an expression's value evaluates to `NULL` it will return `NULL`. As `RecordID` (which is what `COALESCE(i.Personid,NULL)` is being inserted into) can't have the value `NULL` the `INSERT` fails and the whole transaction is rolled back.

I suspect that what you want for your trigger is the below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AuditRecord ON dbo.Persons
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AppLog (TableName,
                        ColumnName,
                        RecordId,
                        OldValue,
                        NewValue,
                        UpdatedBy,
                        UpdatedOn)
    SELECT 'Persons',
           'LastName',
           i.Personid,
           d.LastName,
           i.LastName,
           CURRENT_USER,
           GETDATE()
    FROM inserted AS i
         LEFT JOIN deleted AS d ON i.Personid = d.Personid;
END;
```

`inserted` will always have at least 1 row for an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT`. `inserted` would not for a `DELETE`, but your trigger won't fire on that DML event so using `inserted` as the "base" table seems the correct choice.

Comment: How the Entered Table is retaining a record after a successful insert till the next Insert, I tried doing a commit before the next insert still the issue did not resolve. I tried to segregate the Audit of Insert delete and update then only the code ran.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppLog](
[TableName] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
[ColumnName] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
[RecordId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[OldValue] [varchar](2000) NULL,
[NewValue] [varchar](2000) NULL,
[UpdatedBy] [varchar](200) NULL,
[UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons](
[Personid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Age] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER AuditRecord ON dbo.Persons
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS

if exists(SELECT * from inserted) and exists (SELECT * from deleted)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO AppLog
    (TableName ,ColumnName ,RecordId ,OldValue ,NewValue ,UpdatedBy ,UpdatedOn )
        SELECT 'Persons', 'LastName', COALESCE(i.Personid,NULL), 
                                    d.LastName, i.LastName, CURRENT_USER, GETDATE()
            FROM Persons pv
             INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON pv.Personid = i.Personid
            INNER JOIN DELETED d ON pv.Personid = d.Personid;

END
If exists (Select * from inserted) and not exists(Select * from deleted)
begin


            INSERT INTO AppLog
    (TableName ,ColumnName ,RecordId ,OldValue ,NewValue ,UpdatedBy ,UpdatedOn )
        SELECT
    'Persons', 'LastName',i.Personid,NULL,i.LastName,CURRENT_USER,GETDATE()
FROM
    inserted AS i


END

GO



INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,age)
VALUES ('Satish','Parida',40);

INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,age)
VALUES ('SKP','Tada',90);

INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,age)
VALUES ('abc','def',90);

INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,age)
VALUES ('gg','hh',90);

UPDATE dbo.Persons SET LastName='Paridachanged' WHERE Personid=1


SELECT * FROM Persons
SELECT * FROM AppLog
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE KnockKnockDev;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AuditRecord', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
DROP TRIGGER dbo.AuditRecord;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER AuditRecord ON dbo.Persons
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
DECLARE @Action as char(1)
DECLARE @Count as int
DECLARE @TableName as char(32)
DECLARE @ColumnName as char (32)

SET @TableName = 'Persons'
SET @ColumnName = 'LastName'
SET @Action = 'I'               -- Set Action to 'I'nsert by default.

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM DELETED

IF @Count > 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED
    IF @Count > 0
        SET @Action = 'U'       -- Set Action to 'U'pdated.
    ELSE
        SET @Action = 'D'       -- Set Action to 'D'eleted.
END

IF @Action = 'I'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AppLog
    (TableName ,ColumnName ,RecordId ,OldValue ,NewValue ,Action ,UpdatedBy ,UpdatedOn )
        SELECT @TableName, @ColumnName, Personid, 
                                    NULL, LastName, @Action, CURRENT_USER, GETDATE()
            FROM INSERTED;
END

ELSE IF @Action = 'D'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AppLog
    (TableName ,ColumnName ,RecordId ,OldValue ,NewValue ,Action ,UpdatedBy ,UpdatedOn )
        SELECT @TableName, @ColumnName, Personid, 
                                    LastName, NULL, @Action, CURRENT_USER, GETDATE()
            FROM DELETED;
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AppLog
        (TableName ,ColumnName ,RecordId ,OldValue ,NewValue ,Action ,UpdatedBy ,UpdatedOn )
            SELECT @TableName, @ColumnName, i.Personid, 
                                        d.LastName, i.LastName, @Action, CURRENT_USER, GETDATE()
                FROM Persons pv
                INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON pv.Personid = i.Personid
                INNER JOIN DELETED d ON pv.Personid = d.Personid;
END
GO
```